# Building multiple layers with jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, leaflet, mapbox, jbuilder

I have a layer of points and a layer of lines. The layer is created by jbuilder and Leaflet displays it.
I can create and display the layers individually, but not together.
For one layer, `map.js` has this in part

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
                  .loadURL('map/map_data.geojson')
                  .addTo(map);
featureLayer.on('ready', function(e) {
  map.fitBounds(featureLayer.getBounds());
});
```

`map_controller.rb`:

```
def map_data
  start   = '1895-01-01'
  start   = start.to_date
  finish  = (start + 3.year)
  @lines =  RestoResidLine.where(resto_date: start..finish).select("id, person_id, resto_loc_id, resid_loc_id, resto_name, resto_date, title_resto, resid_date, title_resid, long_resto, lat_resto, long_resid, lat_resid")
end
```

`map_data.json.jbuilder`:

```
json.type "FeatureCollection"
json.features @lines do |line|
  if (line.long_resto && line.long_resid)
    json.type "Feature"
    json.geometry do
        json.type "LineString"
       json.coordinates [[line.long_resto, line.lat_resto], [line.long_resid, line.lat_resid]]
    end
  end 
end
```

map_data.json is made available to `map.js`. But I don't understand the Rails magic of how all of this comes together.

I want a second layer with points. I first tried just adding a second `json.features @points do |line|...end` calling `@lines` in the controller. But only the last one shows up. I thought they might concatenate. I can probably change the definition of the @... to bring in all the needed information, so that would be one solution; but the logic would be ugly.

So I tried creating another file `point_data.json.jbuilder` and adding to `map.js`

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
                  .loadURL('map/point_data.geojson')
                  .addTo(map);
```

Sure enough point_data.json gets build, but it's a 2400-line html  `<title>Action Controller: Exception caught</title>`. The `map_data.json` is built and displays correctly.

Is this a naming problem? Or? I'm rather new to Rails, ActiveRecord and JavaScript Leaflet.

Code: https://bitbucket.org/MtnBiker/crores5/
I'll try to upload the site so you can see it in (in)action.  Not loading correctly on Heroku.

This can't be that hard. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't set the routes to find point_data, and apparently jbuilder needed that.

```
get 'map' => 'map#index'
get 'map/map_data',   :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
get 'map/point_data', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
get 'map/line_data',  :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

First two already existed, but I forgot to add the latter two. I am now using the latter two. The first was the original, and I split it into these two.

Part of what helped was digging around when the map worked differently on Heroku than at localhost

Forgot about this piece.